# Writing a file with radare2 `w`?

Tags: radare2

Radare2 supports a `w` which writes a string.

```
w foobar             write string 'foobar'
```

However, it doesn't seem to work for me,

```
$ touch foo

$ radare2 ./foo
w foobar
```

The file `foo` remains empty. Am I supposed to flush or save?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### TLDR

- `radare2` opens a file in *`read-only mode` by default*. (see the manual `r2 -h` for further information.)
- to allow *writing to a file*, start radare2 in `write mode` (`r2 -w file`).
- when in a `read-only session` already, `oo+` will *re-open the file* in `write` mode.
- the `cache mode` (`e io.cache=true`) mimics writing access but *changes in radare2 are not actually written to disk*.

### Write Mode - Example

---

1. Open the file `foo` in `write mode`:

   ```
   $ r2 -w foo
   ```

---

2. Print 32 bytes (with `px 32`):

   ```
   [0x00000000]> px 32
   - offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
   0x00000000  ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
   0x00000010  ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
   ```

Note: The first 32 bytes (and the rest of the file) are empty.

---

3. Let's write "Hello World!" into the file:

   ```
   [0x00000000]> w Hello World!
   ```
4. And print the 32 bytes again:

   ```
   [0x00000000]> px 32
   - offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
   0x00000000  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6421 ffff ffff  Hello World!....
   0x00000010  ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
   ```

Great! Now we can see that "Hello World!" is written to the file.

---

5. Let's quit radare2 and `cat` the file to see the content:

   ```
    [0x00000000]> q
   ```

   ```
   $ cat foo
   Hello World!
   ```

---

### Cache Mode - Example

1. Open the file `foo` in write mode:

   ```
   $ r2 foo
   ```
2. Print the first 32 bytes@

   ```
   [0x00000000]> px 32
   - offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
   0x00000000  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6421 ffff ffff  Hello World!....
   0x00000010  ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
   ```
3. Activate 'cache mode`:

   ```
   [0x00000000]> e io.cache=true
   ```
4. Make some changes in radare2:

   ```
   [0x00000000]> w Goodbyte World! :)
   ```
5. Proof that radare2 mimicked writing as if in `write mode`:

   ```
   [0x00000000]> px 32
   - offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
   0x00000000  476f 6f64 6279 7465 2057 6f72 6c64 2120  Goodbyte World!
   0x00000010  3a29 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  :)..............
   ```
6. Quit radare2:

   ```
   [0x00000000]> q
   ```
7. Examine actual file contents:

   ```
   $ cat foo
   Hello World!
   ```

   Note: The file didn't change! That's the effect of `cache mode`.

Comment: What does `-w` do outside of write mode?

Comment: Well, it allows radare2 to write to the file. i.e modifying the original file. This is risky and should be careful while using it. While working with write-mode you can work regularly with radare2 as you are used to. It doesn't change a thing. Also, please see my edition the the answer -- regardless your comment, I elaborated more :)

Comment: The follow up question is though what does `w foobar` do if radare opens the file in read-only mode? Is it just a noop?

Comment: yup. Not doing a thing. I suggest you explore the powers of the `w` command and subcommands of radare2. I use it on a daily basis - check out `w?` for commands like `wtf`, `wox`, `wopD`...

Answer (score 0):

Just to update @Megabeets answer.

When you start with an empty file (created by `touch`), the `w` command will not work by default even if the `r2` will be started in `write` mode. The missing information is, in that case, the mapping

```
[0x00000000]> om
[0x00000000]
```

Returns an empty result. Apart from listing, the `om` command can also be used to create the mapping:

```
Usage: om[-] [arg]   # map opened files
| om                                       list all defined IO maps
...
| om fd vaddr [size] [paddr] [rwx] [name]  create new io map
...
```

In order to do the mapping, one needs to specify (for example) the following command

```
[0x00000000]> om 3 0x0 12
[0x00000000]> om
 1 fd: 3 +0x00000000 0x00000000 - 0x0000000b rwx
```

That will create, for the file description 3, a 12 bytes in size mapping starting from an address 0x0.

After that `w` will work:

```
[0x00000000]> w Hello world!
[0x00000000]> px 32
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x00000000  4865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 6421 ffff ffff  Hello world!....
0x00000010  ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
[0x00000000]>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Create an input/output mapping to allow writing to a non-mapped file

To **allow writing** up to `64 byte` starting at `offset 0x00000000`, map changes in radare2 **to `file descriptor 3`** (the file opened in radare2).

```
[0x00000000]> om 3 0x0 64
[0x00000000]> om
1 fd: 3 +0x00000000 0x00000000 - 0x0000000b rwx
```

### Explanation

**An empty file** (as created by `touch`) **has no input/output mappings** (even when opened with in `write mode`).
To confirm no region has been mapped, you can list all defined IO maps with the radare2-command `om`.)

To create an i/o-mapping use `om` with parameters:

> om fd vaddr [size] [paddr] [rwx] [name]  create new io map

## Example

```
radare2 -w test_file
 -- What has been executed cannot be unexecuted
[0x00000000]> w This won't be written anywhere, because no mapping exists.
[0x00000000]> om
[0x00000000]> om 3 0 64
[0x00000000]> om
 1 fd: 3 +0x00000000 0x00000000 - 0x0000003f rwx 
[0x00000000]> w Hello World!
[0x00000000]> V
```

[image: hexview of file after mapping and writing]